# Generate a vector that is orthogonal to a set of other vectors in any dimension

Tags: python, matrix, orthogonal

Assume I have a set of vectors $ a_1, ..., a_d $ that are orthonormal to each other. Now, I want to find another vector $ a_{d+1} $ that is orthogonal to all the other vectors.

1. Is there an efficient algorithm to achieve this? I can only think of adding a random vector to the end, and then applying gram-schmidt.
2. Is there a python library which already achieves this?

Comment: why can you not take the general wege products of all the vectors? If they are all in n dimensions, and you have n-1 of them, then you can take the cross product of all them to get the last orthogonal vector

Comment: Good point actually.. didn't think of that. Is this true for any kind of vectors? Also, is it possible also if I have "n-2" vectors, but "n" dimesions?

Comment: Taking the cross product isnt how gram schmidt works

Comment: I know... modesitt's points, however, was easily valid for finding an n'th orthogonal vector, given that you have n-1 vectors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/712030/217789). Can't speak to optimality, but here is a working solution. The good thing is that `numpy.linalg` does all of the heavy lifting, so this may be speedier and more robust than doing Gram-Schmidt by hand. Besides, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84495/computational-complexity-of-least-square-regression-operation) suggests that the complexity is not worse than Gram-Schmidt.

The idea:

1. Treat your input orthogonal vectors as columns of a matrix `O`.
2. Add another random column to `O`. Generically `O` will remain a full-rank matrix.
3. Choose `b = [0, 0, ..., 0, 1]` with `len(b) = d + 1`.
4. Solve a least-squares problem `x O = b`. Then, `x` is guaranteed to be non-zero and orthogonal to all original columns of `O`.

---

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import lstsq
from scipy.linalg import orth

# random matrix
M = np.random.rand(10, 5)

# get 5 orthogonal vectors in 10 dimensions in a matrix form
O = orth(M)


def find_orth(O):
    rand_vec = np.random.rand(O.shape[0], 1)
    A = np.hstack((O, rand_vec))
    b = np.zeros(O.shape[1] + 1)
    b[-1] = 1
    return lstsq(A.T, b)[0]


res = find_orth(O)

if all(np.abs(np.dot(res, col)) < 10e-9 for col in O.T):
    print("Success")
else:
    print("Failure")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) However, I don't understand why you choose b and solve for x? I mean, we cannot change O after w have added the random column to O, but we would want the property np.dot( O.T, O ) = I, right?

Comment: I guess I could have phrased it better. We "add" a random column temporarily. We then solve for `x` that is orthogonal to all of the original columns but _not_ the random column. In particular, `x` is not zero. So x would correspond to a_{d+1} in your terminology. BTW `np.dot(O.T, O) = I` would imply that the vectors are orthonormal. Orthogonal vectors would lead to a diagonal matrix.